# moduleResolution: bundler causing module resolution errors with certain modules in VSCode

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, typescript-module-resolution

I have `moduleResolution` set to `bundler` - my tsconfig looks like this:

```json
{
    "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["vite/client"]
    }
}
```

(`@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json` sets moduleResolution to bundler)

When I try to import the `broadcast-channel` package, VS Code gives me a TS 2307 error.

Here are the relevant parts of broadcast-channel's package.json:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "node": {
        "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
        "import": "./dist/esnode/index.js",
        "default": "./dist/es5node/index.js"
      },
      "browser": {
        "types": "./types/index.d.ts",
        "import": "./dist/esbrowser/index.js",
        "default": "./dist/lib/index.es5.js"
      }
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "main": "./dist/es5node/index.js",
  "module": "./dist/esnode/index.js",
  "browser": "./dist/lib/index.es5.js",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "types": "./types/index.d.ts"
}
```

When I set `moduleResolution` to `node` manually in my tsconfig, the error goes away. **Why does it even occur in the first place?** Importing other modules like `idb` works.

---

I'm using Typescript 5.1.6 with Volar 1.8.8 running in takeover mode. VS Code 1.80.2.